# How should I filter blocked user contents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've created little social website which has user generated content in it. And users have option to block each other if they don't like what they post.

So I'm using postgresql and I have three simple tables.

```
Table User
id (pk)  | user_name
1        | a
2        | b
3        | c

Table Post
id (pk)  | user_id (fk) | content
1        | 1            | s
2        | 3            | a
3        | 2            | m
4        | 2            | p

Table Block
id (pk) | blocker_id (fk)  | blocked_id (fk)
1       | 1                | 2
```

#### What I expect when I hit the search button:

- user1 should see his own posts and user3's posts because user2 is blocked.
- user2 should see his own posts and user3's posts because she got blocked by user1.
- user3 should see his own posts, user2's and user1's posts.

#### Sql

I wrote an sql but couldn't wrote an elastic search query. Here is the sql statement:

```
select *
from Post p
where
not exists (select id
from Block
where ((Block.blocked_id = p.user_id) and (Block.blocker_id = @current_user_id)) or ((Block.blocked_id = @current_user_id) and (Block.blocker_id = p.user_id))
```

What should I do?